Delete request to idrive e2 not working on VPS
I have a function that uploads images to idrive e2 and another to delete it. uploads work perfectly. Delete gives 404.
        const response = await axios.post(`https://api.heartstribute.com/api/upload/${userId}/${profileId}`, formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        });


this works but the delete doesn't:
      const response = await axios.delete(`https://api.heartstribute.com/api/delete`, {
        params: { fileUrl }
      });

however if i replace delete url to http://localhost:3000/api/delete and run the backend locally, it works.
for reference my backend code is:
router.delete('/delete', async (req, res) => {
  const fileUrl = req.query.fileUrl;

  if (!fileUrl) {
    return res.status(400).send('File URL is required');
  }
  

  try {
    const key = fileUrl.replace(publicUrl, '');
    console.log(key);
    const sanitizedKey = key.startsWith('/') ? key.slice(1) : key;

    console.log('Deleting file with key:', sanitizedKey);

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'heartstribute.bucket',
      Key: sanitizedKey,
    };

     s3.deleteObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error:", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Success:", data);
      }});
    
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'File deleted successfully' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error deleting file:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Error deleting file: ' + err.message);
  }
});

i simply get a 404 (Not Found) when running on server. does it have anything to do with nginx configuration?
server {
    server_name api.heartstribute.com; # Replace with your domain name

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.heartstribute.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.heartstribute.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = api.heartstribute.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

if its working locally, i feel that maybe the issue is how the server is configured, or perhaps the path for deletion shouldn't be api.heartstribute.com. but that's the one that i'm using for upload so how come it doesn't work for delete?
